# Does entity name length impact program performance in case of reflection?

Tags: java, performance, reflection

in the case of using reflection we are accessing entities by their names encoded in strings like this `m = getMethod("someMethod")`. To find the requested entity a string comparison has to be done.  Does it mean that the length of the entity name influences the performance. If it so how much is this impact on the performance?

Comment: There is no reflection in c++. Please do use tags that are unrelated to your question.

Comment: ...please do **not** use tags that are unrealted to your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is heavily dependent on the Java Virtual Machine, you're using. I wrote a test program, just to get some numbers for a JVM 1.8.0_05 (yes, it's old ;-):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class ReflectionAccessTest {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            // do some "training"
            ReflectionTarget.class.getMethod("a", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
            ReflectionTarget.class.getMethod("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
            ReflectionTarget.class.getMethod("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
        }

        Method method = null;;
        long start;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // do some "training"
            method = ReflectionTarget.class.getMethod("a", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
        }
        System.out.println("Time to get method with short name " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            method.invoke(null, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        }
        System.out.println("Time to execute method with short name " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // do some "training"
            method = ReflectionTarget.class.getMethod("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
        }
        System.out.println("Time to get method with medium name " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            method.invoke(null, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        }
        System.out.println("Time to execute method with medium name " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            // do some "training"
            method = ReflectionTarget.class.getMethod("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
        }
        System.out.println("Time to get method with long name " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            method.invoke(null, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        }
        System.out.println("Time to execute method with long name " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    private static class ReflectionTarget {
        public static void a(int a, int b) {
            // do nothing
        }

        public static void aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa(int a, int b) {
            // do nothing
        }

        public static void aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa(int a, int b) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Time to get method with short name 1012 ms
Time to execute method with short name 58 ms
Time to get method with medium name 3690 ms
Time to execute method with medium name 177 ms
Time to get method with long name 6279 ms
Time to execute method with long name 180 ms
```

The times are actually dependent on the length of the name (that surprised me first but on second thought it's obvious because there needs to be some kind of equaliy-test that is length-dependent).

But you can also see that the impact is negligible. A call of `getMethod` takes 0.1 nanoseconds for a method with a name with only one character and takes 0.6 nanoseconds for a method with a crazy long name (haven't counted the number of `a`s).

If this difference is actually relevant for you, you might try out caching-mechanisms of the method you retrieved. But dependent on the time the called method takes, that might be completely useless unless its execution time is also in the range of sub-nanoseconds.

Comment: Please use proper benchmarking libraries, there is so many things that JIT might affect.
Otherwise for any often-used reflections you should only get method once.

Comment: Even using name directly in code might affect performance here